# how to combine mutiple command as one by a function?

Tags: linux, shell

I have often using some combined command like `find . -name *.rb -print|xargs grep -n --color=auto current` or `history|grep xx` or else. So, how to write a function, say 'anfind', and i can call it with two arguments,'rb' and 'current', then it can display the result ?
like this:

```
$ anfind
  (wait for two arguments) rb help
  (display)result
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own function inside your .profile or .bashrc file like this (or within a script):

```
anfind() {
    find . -name ...etc
}
```

Then within your function, you can use arguments with `$1`, `$2`, etc. An example:

```
echo_args() {
    echo "First arg: $1 - Second arg: $2"
}

$ echo_args Hello world
First arg: Hello - Second arg: world
```

Comment: I put it in a script named fire,    
       
     #!/bin/bash  
    function f(){
     find . -name *.$1|xargs grep -n --color=auto $2
    }
    f       then i run `./fire rb help` but it show nothing. why?

Comment: Putting it in a script is fine as well, just do the same as above.

Comment: @Ziu If you put it in a script and run it like `./myscript` then you need to make sure to actually call the function inside the script by e.g. putting `f "$@"` at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, I forget pass the argument to the function. Now , it works